# Postgres 9.6: tune for one time import

Tags: postgresql, import

I'm using [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/) to perform a one-time migration from MySQL to Postgres.

For that purpose, I want to temporarily configure Postgres specifically for that workload.

- reduce WAL as much as possible: `wal_level = minimal`
- `archive_mode = off`
- Should I `autovacuum = off` ?

What else can I do to improve things without severely putting my data at risk?

Ee.g. I don't want to `fsync = off`. Although I can re-do this migration, this additional time would still be unwanted.

#### Additional setting after Feedback

- `synchronous_commit=off` (thanks @a_horse_with_no_name )

Comment: `synchronous_commit=off` and if you are on an older Postgres version most probably also need to increase `checkpoint_segments`

Comment: Dang, knew I forgot something. I'm using 9.6, updated the questions title. Also added your suggestion, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the following changes to postgres.conf yielded the best results so far:

```
archive_mode            = off       # old: on
autovacuum              = off       # old: on
commit_delay            = 100000    # old: 0
maintenance_work_mem    = 1GB       # old: 512MB
max_wal_size            = 10GB      # old: 1GB
synchronous_commit      = off       # old: on
wal_level               = minimal   # old: archive
work_mem                = 1GB       # old: 8MB
```

Also I had quite trouble getting the most out of a single pgloader invocation to migrate all the table. This would have been the most desired way, because pgloader that way also re-creates all the FK between the imported tables.

But the problems I was facing (pgloader hanging, not achieving the performance I was aiming for in terms of total time) I settled with this approach:

- run a separate pgloader instance for every individual table, in parallel, inside `tmux`
- using `tmux wait-for` the longest import migration
- run a separate `*.sql` script for (almost each) table for post-processing (add FKs, add triggers), again in parallel inside a tmux
- run `vacuumdb --jobs=24 --analyze`

To fit this purpose, the machine in question had been pimped:

- 14 cores (instead of 8)
- 64GB RAM (instead of 32GB; but they will eventually stay)

Also, for each individual pgloader invocation I had a seperate loader config with individual `batch size` configuration. The default batch size of `25000` wouldn't work for the bigger tables.

In the end, for my purpose and workload, this cut down the time

- from 4h38m (1h11m importing, 1h41m adding FKs, 1h22 vacuuming)
- to **2h8m6s** (74m30s importing, 25m50s adding FKs, 27m44s vacuuming)

(Actually, the latest numbers are slightly below 2h even, but I don't have more detailed stats for them)